# how to train image segmentation task on tpu's in colab?

Tags: tensorflow

This is the code I have written in which I have created a custom data generator. As per the error even if I copy my loss function and metric function and paste it in strategy.scope() it is throwing the error. Can anyone tell me how to use tpu in a correct way. Because training on gpu is taking a very long time. It's the first time I am trying to use tpu's.

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  training_model = Model(inputs,final_layer)
  def soft_dice_loss(y_true,pred):
    y_true=K.flatten(y_true)
    pred=K.flatten(pred)
    intersec=(2*K.sum(y_true*pred))+1e-9
    deno=K.sum(y_true**2)+K.sum(pred**2)+1e-9
    return 1-K.mean(intersec/deno)
  def soft_dice_coeff(y_true,pred):
    y_true=K.flatten(y_true)
    pred=K.flatten(pred)
    intersec=(2*K.sum(y_true*pred))+1e-9
    deno=K.sum(K.abs(y_true))+K.sum(K.abs(pred))+1e-9
    return K.mean(intersec/deno)
  training_model.compile(
      optimizer='Adam',
      loss=soft_dice_loss,
      metrics=[soft_dice_coeff])

train_generator=DataGenerator(batch_size=4*strategy.num_replicas_in_sync,
                              dataframe=train_image_csv,
                              x_col='images',
                              y_col=['class1','class2','class3','class4'],
                              number_classes=4,
                              dimensions=[256, 1600, 3],
                              shuffle=True)
valid_generator=DataGenerator(batch_size=4*strategy.num_replicas_in_sync,
                              dataframe=valid_image_csv,
                              x_col='images',
                              y_col=['class1','class2','class3','class4'],
                              number_classes=4,
                              dimensions=[256, 1600, 3],
                              shuffle=True)
training_model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=20,callbacks=[checking],validation_data=valid_generator)
```

but, getting an error as:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_compile(self, optimizer, metrics, **kwargs)
   2510               'with strategy.scope():\n'
   2511               '  model=_create_model()\n'
-> 2512               '  model.compile(...)' % (v, strategy))
   2513 
 Model metrics must be created in the same distribution strategy scope
ValueError: Variable (<tf.Variable 'conv2d_15/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 2.86176484e-02,  2.51885027e-01, -1.83856204e-01,
          -1.97255760e-02,  4.81729269e-01,  3.76131624e-01,
           3.87416780e-01,  1.48169428e-01,  3.13540459e-01,
          -4.39419270e-01,  9.91959125e-02,  2.35064223e-01,
          -1.62009656e-01,  4.49633867e-01,  5.09046912e-02,
          -4.74250317e-01, -5.30071892e-02,  1.28139153e-01,
          -2.75510550e-01, -3.36916968e-02,  2.44992077e-01,
           3.58369410e-01,  1.36849955e-01,  3.74716446e-02,
           1.62962437e-01,  5.02037001e-04,  1.77659914e-01,
          -9.66658965e-02,  4.27701801e-01, -5.85712254e-01,
          -1.66672274e-01, -3.39204520e-01],
         [ 3.46261173e-01, -1.99010447e-01,  4.23968546e-02,
           2.28120256e-02, -1.14684001e-01,  2.48983935e-01,
           2.76021004e-01, -3.77522956e-04,  3.75428289e-01,
           1.42228365e-01,  4.39973593e-01,  4.84382212e-02,
          -5.64863205e-01, -2.06808805e-01,  3.19215178e-01,
           7.98675045e-02, -4.42748889e-02,  7.54454732e-02,
           8.99273753e-02,  4.14310098e-01, -1.11849628e-01,
          -1.27662316e-01, -2.91237146e-01, -1.39686391e-01,
          -2.10033074e-01,  1.26605600e-01,  7.78739005e-02,
          -2.12735206e-01,  1.90240130e-01, -1.45447955e-01,
          -1.76703289e-01,  3.04714561e-01],
         [-6.52107745e-02,  3.65301818e-01, -1.36743579e-02,
          -2.98343468e-02,  3.47715616e-01, -1.37570407e-02,
          -2.48846784e-01, -1.88701555e-01, -3.08151748e-02,
          -3.25779468e-01,  8.78698900e-02,  4.31671619e-01,
           3.56842041e-01, -3.76637459e-01,  7.71616474e-02,
           1.17426030e-01,  3.95104408e-01, -1.81418002e-01,
          -1.72196090e-01,  3.83048117e-01, -4.58553582e-02,
           2.05911100e-01, -3.05244207e-01, -2.09702611e-01,
          -3.30514014e-02,  1.05384506e-01, -1.75219730e-01,
           2.79307961e-01, -1.16290696e-01, -4.39702421e-01,
           2.41252184e-01,  4.78073418e-01]],

        [[-4.89468649e-02, -4.76409048e-01, -4.13135231e-01,
          -1.35060906e-01, -7.63120949e-02,  4.79692295e-02,
          -1.97806507e-01, -3.59104753e-01, -3.75104874e-01,
          -4.13594872e-01, -2.13686004e-01, -1.98894754e-01,
           5.53006530e-01, -4.68982935e-01,  4.61025119e-01,
          -1.89402804e-01,  5.59908748e-01, -1.79287419e-01,
           5.86298883e-01, -9.17174965e-02,  5.35481155e-01,
           4.88064468e-01,  3.06340903e-01,  5.17639448e-04,
          -2.98851073e-01, -1.19137354e-02, -3.38854780e-03,
           4.98219356e-02, -2.47040808e-01, -5.51256776e-01,
           4.97029245e-01,  4.20889676e-01],
         [-1.03122570e-01, -2.87807912e-01,  2.66193867e-01,
          -8.69771987e-02,  8.86021480e-02, -3.24584424e-01,
           3.41594666e-01, -3.64764094e-01, -2.47306764e-01,
          -1.17799744e-01,  3.08235679e-02, -7.24501684e-02,
          -2.61525810e-01,  2.05430374e-01, -2.63343245e-01,
           6.25704462e-03,  1.01438574e-01, -2.70783186e-01,
          -3.91700804e-01,  3.32344800e-01, -3.44174027e-01,
           1.53317764e-01, -2.61125565e-01,  5.97038925e-01,
           1.13877483e-01,  5.21202743e-01,  1.03106745e-01,
          -5.68401098e-01,  7.81430230e-02, -1.67003527e-01,
          -5.91756165e-01,  4.57226276e-01],
         [ 2.51822889e-01, -1.78199053e-01,  1.10666789e-01,
          -3.88121426e-01,  5.31099498e-01, -7.31657520e-02,
          -1.41270757e-01, -8.21648538e-02,  3.46988812e-02,
          -3.21497947e-01, -1.65262267e-01,  5.93707979e-01,
          -8.28797445e-02,  6.62447363e-02, -5.65414011e-01,
           1.03073649e-01,  2.12193638e-01,  1.70026720e-01,
           1.39139742e-01,  1.05345517e-03, -1.95384532e-01,
          -1.13502122e-01, -2.81079143e-01,  4.61337239e-01,
          -9.20106918e-02,  1.53996095e-01,  1.19066862e-02,
           2.05515325e-01,  2.35743914e-02, -1.47897229e-01,
          -4.34656084e-01, -1.87039077e-01]],

        [[-6.14758074e-01,  4.92858112e-01, -1.19309746e-01,
          -2.23623678e-01, -5.79516470e-01, -1.79681078e-01,
          -3.46052885e-01, -8.71743858e-02,  2.25869134e-01,
           1.14158355e-01,  1.05970986e-01, -2.43968681e-01,
          -2.89411038e-01,  1.15846852e-02, -7.63337500e-03,
           1.31254852e-01, -7.79125020e-02, -2.33210698e-01,
           2.51863394e-02, -4.26686049e-01,  5.49371064e-01,
          -2.37284482e-01, -1.60655957e-02, -2.20923841e-01,
          -4.02859598e-01,  2.70713270e-01, -8.23754966e-02,
          -2.87027508e-01, -3.63216400e-02, -4.86215234e-01,
           4.87836808e-01, -1.20586060e-01],
         [ 2.54249990e-01,  5.37907302e-01,  1.74036175e-01,
          -5.04967332e-01, -3.91066372e-02,  1.62895024e-01,
          -1.30039662e-01, -1.79916248e-01, -3.00860196e-01,
           4.25611794e-01,  1.15126327e-01, -5.22004366e-01,
          -1.28336295e-01, -5.03660887e-02, -3.45173806e-01,
           5.62976480e-01,  1.01731151e-01, -5.72150350e-01,
          -2.26676371e-02, -2.74738669e-01, -2.13455543e-01,
           2.41733436e-02, -3.38131696e-01,  1.66502237e-01,
          -9.82914045e-02, -9.25891176e-02,  1.33591190e-01,
           1.20383024e-01,  2.61100605e-02,  4.49265726e-02,
           2.72643805e-01, -8.58548209e-02],
         [ 2.22129300e-01, -4.62873979e-03,  8.03247020e-02,
           3.16274613e-01, -1.22645460e-01,  2.61154771e-01,
           3.88606600e-02, -5.10409474e-01,  2.18108743e-01,
          -1.30703282e-02,  5.23315012e-01,  2.25734711e-01,
          -8.77627432e-02,  1.91031039e-01,  4.56811875e-01,
          -6.09081089e-01,  1.95014447e-01, -1.17128730e-01,
          -2.47346550e-01,  2.75673002e-01,  1.47225469e-01,
           3.00564528e-01, -2.20195562e-01,  4.85742725e-02,
          -3.38689983e-01,  1.08774722e-01, -8.98633599e-02,
           1.39428049e-01, -2.61856437e-01, -4.71997783e-02,
           3.15194249e-01,  1.91212445e-02]]],


       [[[-4.93359804e-01, -2.01804474e-01, -4.72745625e-03,
          -1.84519008e-01,  8.18349048e-02, -4.39105272e-01,
          -9.82239023e-02, -3.90078455e-01, -2.40056738e-01,
           1.29183717e-02, -4.51702178e-01, -1.04296431e-01,
           1.32625893e-01, -1.18902199e-01, -2.06202745e-01,
          -2.93851942e-01, -3.24891835e-01,  7.65667558e-02,
           2.35038295e-01, -1.39201969e-01,  8.60341415e-02,
           4.80076700e-01, -1.69387519e-01,  3.23268175e-01,
          -1.78106762e-02, -3.55972439e-01,  1.99166462e-01,
          -1.33314341e-01, -7.69288242e-02, -3.20708543e-01,
          -9.33207646e-02,  4.07715201e-01],
         [ 7.68108517e-02,  2.78671563e-01,  2.01580614e-01,
           6.21752478e-02,  1.37449563e-01, -4.69423681e-01,
           2.62439530e-02,  1.22409306e-01,  7.96807632e-02,
          -3.53483170e-01,  2.54092067e-02, -1.31838202e-01,
          -1.86308026e-01, -1.05770335e-01,  2.65639305e-01,
          -7.80920461e-02, -1.63143396e-01,  7.49984011e-03,
          -2.58349925e-01,  2.19718605e-01, -3.51031899e-01,
           7.25683570e-02,  1.97273999e-01,  3.26114520e-02,
          -3.72522235e-01,  4.02222365e-01, -8.99733454e-02,
          -2.02027917e-01,  1.51410460e-01, -1.65729761e-01,
           1.56738888e-02,  3.50104034e-01],
         [ 3.17899473e-02, -7.06443861e-02,  4.11774427e-01,
          -9.68843922e-02, -5.28492033e-01,  2.72653729e-01,
          -1.82894647e-01,  2.76882201e-01,  4.47149068e-01,
           4.80375439e-01,  4.83195305e-01,  2.08107352e-01,
           4.44305211e-01,  2.53468603e-01,  7.57752955e-02,
          -2.51574486e-01,  1.32874012e-01, -5.17523468e-01,
          -2.76025981e-01,  7.52711967e-02, -5.67685999e-02,
           1.83212906e-01,  1.43455878e-01,  3.58684659e-01,
          -4.87156481e-01, -1.89680174e-01, -1.81944504e-01,
           4.05059636e-01,  2.22765222e-01,  1.24186110e-02,
           3.05987537e-01,  2.70503819e-01]],

        [[ 2.48240530e-01, -1.56648487e-01,  3.78404073e-02,
           9.66628343e-02, -3.48707974e-01, -1.46622807e-01,
           4.37899470e-01,  9.53941345e-02, -6.10571243e-02,
          -9.67848673e-02,  7.82505572e-02,  4.93700832e-01,
           2.56548431e-02, -3.95281203e-02,  5.43864705e-02,
          -5.57845086e-03, -1.90100163e-01,  1.74574181e-01,
          -4.36696485e-02,  2.18895748e-01,  1.09487548e-01,
           2.47687683e-01,  8.45225714e-03, -1.23866685e-01,
          -4.85353395e-02, -4.84737344e-02, -4.92983192e-01,
           9.87549573e-02, -1.23108245e-01,  1.87457293e-01,
          -2.48716310e-01,  5.46015143e-01],
         [ 2.36256361e-01, -5.81218265e-02, -1.04359083e-01,
           4.36425775e-01, -5.10727763e-01,  3.01727019e-02,
           1.42845675e-01, -8.13578516e-02, -1.36902735e-01,
           4.27270383e-01, -1.01132922e-01,  2.19416916e-01,
           4.59086955e-01,  2.11566240e-01, -3.23427737e-01,
           2.99140900e-01,  1.43798679e-01,  3.01356494e-01,
           5.52968740e-01, -5.12594819e-01, -1.07348405e-01,
          -1.56996518e-01,  1.25101224e-01,  4.15906608e-01,
           6.28912523e-02,  1.17557682e-01, -1.08321697e-01,
           1.25701442e-01,  3.49775672e-01,  3.90670478e-01,
          -3.63242328e-01, -3.15430671e-01],
         [-8.23011175e-02,  4.47536826e-01, -1.43859843e-02,
          -3.80643785e-01,  1.60219334e-02, -1.63250223e-01,
          -2.73935109e-01, -2.90098749e-02, -2.84009632e-02,
           1.73034295e-02,  3.42511296e-01,  1.17809244e-01,
          -8.52238834e-02,  1.55760825e-01, -1.80561423e-01,
           1.20164856e-01, -1.95611581e-01,  3.75216186e-01,
           3.98647279e-01,  9.43479836e-02,  2.82988310e-01,
          -3.47589940e-01,  4.57324654e-01, -3.64818005e-03,
           4.69411671e-01,  1.00957379e-01, -8.19386542e-02,
          -4.31396484e-01, -4.00332808e-01,  3.95217836e-01,
          -3.34284186e-01, -2.99580157e-01]],

        [[ 1.24260135e-01,  4.74044651e-01, -1.41138583e-01,
          -1.30208760e-01,  2.71903485e-01,  3.30214411e-01,
           1.55008128e-02, -3.16642076e-02, -1.49157315e-01,
          -4.85127449e-01,  4.98222500e-01,  4.65350986e-01,
           1.49620533e-01,  6.18687980e-02,  3.39400247e-02,
           4.76102561e-01,  8.39800313e-02,  4.92318839e-01,
           2.06052199e-01, -1.76542610e-01, -1.26267388e-01,
          -8.54324475e-02, -1.64342970e-01,  3.22677732e-01,
           1.87796488e-01,  1.14178814e-01,  3.18328999e-02,
          -9.75107402e-02,  1.26417920e-01,  1.99822754e-01,
          -5.21033108e-01,  7.90865570e-02],
         [-1.29153088e-01, -4.95727867e-01, -1.55050755e-01,
          -6.04258597e-01, -2.99085677e-01,  1.23091832e-01,
           3.08648378e-01,  4.46541637e-01, -4.10341293e-01,
           7.81817287e-02,  1.39485728e-02,  4.07051831e-01,
           3.87740582e-01,  4.29334752e-02,  2.72099286e-01,
           3.92681271e-01, -1.61614180e-01, -2.31923148e-01,
          -1.18421257e-01,  8.33435282e-02, -3.62244397e-01,
           8.75436235e-03,  1.07104912e-01, -3.66980024e-02,
           3.39902550e-01, -6.80892169e-02, -4.63341266e-01,
           2.99327046e-01,  1.14754543e-01,  4.96079892e-01,
           1.05848074e-01, -1.92485023e-02],
         [-4.97262180e-01,  4.81447205e-02, -2.80200332e-01,
           1.47234514e-01,  3.57034206e-01,  3.20632517e-01,
           1.33988649e-01,  2.12241992e-01,  3.70979577e-01,
           1.50920093e-01,  3.51582259e-01,  3.54921781e-02,
          -4.58651572e-01, -1.51228398e-01, -4.23863024e-01,
          -2.02565551e-01, -4.08915967e-01,  5.62419444e-02,
          -3.63487422e-01,  5.71728110e-01,  4.96131539e-01,
           5.12773544e-02, -2.81306088e-01,  9.61515903e-02,
           3.01067472e-01, -8.18912983e-02,  4.12836522e-01,
          -2.12496430e-01,  5.69163188e-02,  1.15401223e-01,
          -4.61325228e-01, -1.51605457e-02]]],


       [[[ 2.88666368e-01, -8.44172463e-02, -7.66417980e-02,
           2.06715211e-01,  1.71181764e-02,  3.54682028e-01,
           4.32320625e-01, -1.73062086e-01,  2.67018944e-01,
           2.32173890e-01,  1.58797652e-01, -2.94585049e-01,
          -2.98278987e-01,  2.69727949e-02, -1.18209630e-01,
           4.18613032e-02, -1.26188993e-01,  2.27771923e-01,
          -2.52933264e-01, -3.61352295e-01,  1.77842543e-01,
          -9.14380848e-02,  5.82065463e-01,  3.57030421e-01,
          -2.56323397e-01,  2.04095128e-03,  2.48880550e-01,
          -1.52535141e-01, -5.14613032e-01,  5.61984368e-02,
           1.55444831e-01, -3.15441974e-02],
         [ 2.69836962e-01,  2.15445697e-01, -1.13710210e-01,
           3.25090438e-01,  5.43138206e-01, -1.96523592e-02,
          -1.25923723e-01,  2.91354984e-01,  3.23325038e-01,
           1.69265077e-01,  3.98341939e-02, -1.40851051e-01,
           1.66855603e-01,  1.30212074e-02,  2.46465832e-01,
           2.48280168e-01, -1.89555749e-01, -5.71593754e-02,
           2.65157372e-01,  3.22605669e-01,  7.03409910e-02,
          -4.15904284e-01,  3.13221723e-01,  3.13722342e-01,
           4.07409936e-01, -2.80629992e-01,  1.18686192e-01,
          -9.76002961e-03, -1.68063328e-01,  7.24963397e-02,
           2.25354537e-01,  4.27080840e-01],
         [-2.90867817e-02, -2.18919396e-01,  1.61537305e-01,
          -3.04928511e-01, -4.45891649e-01, -1.62068322e-01,
          -3.05363029e-01, -1.74753051e-02, -2.19122514e-01,
           5.47291785e-02, -3.83583009e-01,  2.37312481e-01,
           3.08570396e-02,  2.91257888e-01, -2.42763236e-02,
          -4.27217275e-01, -2.38388702e-01,  1.12237938e-01,
          -5.69560111e-01,  1.97440758e-01,  3.71146590e-01,
           2.30282053e-01,  1.52074859e-01,  2.34133556e-01,
           1.68894663e-01,  2.56244689e-01, -2.82850116e-01,
           3.59350443e-01, -1.50108591e-01, -1.36213407e-01,
           4.77255642e-01,  3.35809171e-01]],

        [[ 3.79353195e-01, -2.07121685e-01,  2.58564234e-01,
           1.94481179e-01,  5.00347793e-01,  3.31316590e-01,
          -7.95983896e-02, -8.51447582e-02,  5.13869487e-02,
           9.33358148e-02, -2.89737824e-02,  4.08468217e-01,
          -1.67119071e-01, -4.95333761e-01, -3.14049363e-01,
          -3.99738520e-01,  1.11232415e-01,  3.26074243e-01,
          -2.12136224e-01, -5.16901374e-01,  2.52203763e-01,
           5.19047454e-02, -1.60330608e-01,  8.11335593e-02,
           5.33295572e-01, -5.97221181e-02, -1.69608623e-01,
           7.70150498e-02,  2.07502127e-01, -3.52346867e-01,
          -1.86551020e-01, -1.63009599e-01],
         [-2.36284643e-01, -1.34845674e-01, -3.26061636e-01,
          -2.13283803e-02,  3.93905640e-01, -3.52265328e-01,
          -1.93116128e-01,  9.13463309e-02,  2.79034764e-01,
           3.04736942e-01,  6.16026558e-02,  7.99860433e-02,
           9.85851735e-02, -1.35391816e-01,  3.00876558e-01,
          -2.36904994e-01,  2.99291641e-01, -3.07377249e-01,
           4.02982943e-02, -4.40169275e-01,  3.06060240e-02,
           3.50907445e-01, -3.21622759e-01, -1.67722385e-02,
          -6.07806563e-01, -3.59516174e-01,  2.61159658e-01,
          -1.87993944e-01,  1.72307819e-01,  1.55608118e-01,
          -4.38292921e-01, -4.36801985e-02],
         [-1.52560566e-02, -3.29341859e-01, -1.16169028e-01,
           3.54585379e-01,  3.42493653e-01,  4.22219008e-01,
          -6.17470384e-01, -3.32668200e-02, -3.03886235e-01,
           2.82325409e-03,  8.21733102e-02, -1.26605317e-01,
          -1.67413712e-01, -3.34273666e-01,  5.00667505e-02,
          -4.10709977e-01,  2.97024429e-01, -3.77737880e-01,
           1.68153435e-01, -4.05254066e-01, -2.36241117e-01,
          -1.17496764e-02,  3.56608719e-01,  3.96725208e-01,
           5.02474420e-02,  3.34094584e-01, -4.39760566e-01,
          -4.88129228e-01,  2.17839867e-01,  2.90948600e-01,
           2.86036372e-01, -5.51104993e-02]],

        [[-4.60745171e-02,  5.47011569e-02,  1.61392633e-02,
           2.66970620e-02,  2.61438906e-01,  8.04267824e-02,
          -6.31696731e-03, -1.62909999e-01, -2.14798853e-01,
          -2.53035784e-01, -1.89647060e-02,  1.88106567e-01,
           1.62568182e-01,  3.12040865e-01, -1.54670119e-01,
           1.22320578e-01, -1.93445757e-01,  4.69750851e-01,
           2.41105303e-01, -1.49872005e-01,  3.43296021e-01,
          -1.98070928e-01,  4.08805281e-01, -4.57043737e-01,
           4.35612261e-01, -1.91437155e-01, -1.68325435e-02,
          -3.04106344e-02,  3.77085507e-01,  4.68154430e-01,
           1.05386987e-01,  3.74484450e-01],
         [-1.26730725e-01, -2.31404658e-02,  1.92701995e-01,
           2.48552665e-01,  1.03594037e-02,  5.32559633e-01,
           2.17354938e-01,  1.71402062e-03,  4.67896849e-01,
           2.70731986e-01, -2.17717946e-01,  4.20869589e-02,
           2.63364851e-01,  3.27321053e-01, -5.10298729e-01,
          -1.18739344e-02, -2.87695616e-01,  1.77141204e-01,
          -4.25220340e-01, -5.41199893e-02,  1.03788354e-01,
           5.86137593e-01, -1.95613712e-01,  1.08330853e-01,
          -2.33019199e-02,  1.01976976e-01, -1.32538900e-01,
           1.94541365e-01,  4.34827268e-01,  1.02285873e-02,
           7.86739737e-02,  1.20278344e-01],
         [ 2.05079406e-01, -2.34244883e-01, -1.65973082e-01,
          -3.49957496e-02,  4.74812649e-02,  1.43633559e-01,
           4.10132289e-01,  5.62613130e-01,  4.21896636e-01,
          -3.53376508e-01,  6.16237335e-02,  1.89836085e-01,
           2.57246345e-01, -1.60630465e-01,  3.38688165e-01,
          -1.95534397e-02, -1.57213882e-02, -5.34297347e-01,
          -3.28156501e-01,  2.65008628e-01, -6.18757978e-02,
          -5.47554642e-02,  6.41506240e-02, -7.18553131e-03,
          -3.37415367e-01, -6.28877506e-02, -4.01408136e-01,
          -1.22409686e-02, -2.15484276e-02, -1.80201352e-01,
          -9.61520001e-02, -3.51968408e-01]]]], dtype=float32)>) was not created in the distribution strategy scope of (<tensorflow.python.distribute.tpu_strategy.TPUStrategy object at 0x7f8ff618b4a8>). It is most likely due to not all layers or the model or optimizer being created outside the distribution strategy scope. Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.
with strategy.scope():
  model=_create_model()
  model.compile(...)
```

Comment: Can you add complete traceback?

Comment: edited it @ Aniket Bote.

Comment: Can you add standalone code with dummy data to reproduce this error along with tensorflow version?

Comment: I am using TensorFlow version 2. Sorry! I didn't get it which part of code do you want??

Comment: Minimum possible code to reproduce this error. Replace your data set with synthetic generated data.

Comment: @NagaSai please provide reference to your dataset and minimal reproduce-able code...